# Dictionary of boolean values test at once

Tags: python, dictionary, boolean

Let's say I have a dictionary where I store boolean values.

```
b={'x' : False, 'y' : True, 'z' : False}
```

I have a process that updates the dictionary with new values and I want to test if all are True. I could do a for loop but is there a way to shorten this?

Comment: create a minimal example, but seems like you want `all()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `all`:

```py
all_true = all(b.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

From what you've given you should probably be using the `all()` function.

In your case you should be doing: `all(b.values())`

Hope this helps! And if this is not what you were looking for, feel to comment!